# How to find X,Y coordinates of a single point in ArcMap 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinates

I have a shapefile of a road layout (name: US-101). I drew a line across the road section which intersects the left and right edges of the road and pavement marking (which is also the part of shapefile US-101). Now, I want to find the X, Y coordinates (location in arcmap) of the intersection points of Us-101 and drawn line. The projected coordinate system of dataframe and shapefile is NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_III_FIPS_0403_Feet. This means that the coordinates should be in feet. If I use identify tool, it selects the whole shapefile and gives some location but I am not sure if that represents the location of the particular point I clicked on OR the location of shapefile. Please help me finding the coordinates. Refer to attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your are doing this manually in ArcGIS a quick solution would be to use the [Intersect (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000p000000) tool with the **output type** parameter set to **point**. This will produce point features at each line intersection. You can then simply use the identify tool to pull the point coordinate from the desired location.

If you have to accomplish this many times you can use the same tool and then add an X/Y coordinate field to the output point feature layer and use the Calculate Geometry tool to quickly derive the coordinates for each point.